# Which is most memory efficient to store map in java?

Tags: java, memory, guava

I have to store key value pairs in java which is more memory efficient and which is more time efficient while reading and writing directly in file?

1. Table in guava  `<string,double,double>`
2. map in guava `<string,object>` where object contain two double values.
3. Hashmap in java `<string,object>` where object contain two double values.

also you can suggest some other methods.

Comment: Storing data in memory is one thing and IO to file is another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient is likely to be `Map<String, double[]>` Whether you use Guava or not I don't imagine making much difference.

Comment: Guava's `ImmutableMap` is [more memory-efficient](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures) than `HashMap`, though to be fair the margin isn't that big...at the moment.  (In the future, the margin is likely to widen significantly.)

Comment: But he also asks about reading from / writing to files which implies that the map isn't immutable.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Agreed, just a note. AFAIK, `double[2]` and `class C {double a, b;}` take exactly the same amount of memory.

Comment: Could you reduce the size of a HashMap by increasing its load factor, and minimising its capacity?

Comment: @maaartinus A class of two double is potentially clearer as to the purpose of each `double`

Comment: @maaartinus, that's not true.  `double[2]` will occupy 8 bytes for the object header, 4 bytes for the length field, and 16 bytes for the two `double`s; that may get rounded up to 32 bytes due to alignment constraints.  The `C` class will only take 24 bytes; eight for the object header and 16 for the doubles.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That is true on a 32-bit JVM. On a 64-bit JVm the header is 4 bytes larger, so the size will be the same with alignment.

Comment: Okay, I see how that's true with compressed oops.  Sorry, I should've made that clearer.